# Double wont show on ASPX Page

Tags: c#, double

I am trying to show the value of the query below (Total) on the ASPX page and I keep getting 0. When I put in a breakpoint and debug total all equals 15.0 as it should. The value is saved as a decimal in the MS SQL database it's being pulled from.

.cs Page

```
public partial class Payment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public double total;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var id = Request.Params["ID"];
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd;
        conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("--");
        cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        var sql = String.Format(@"select sum(PayAmt) as total from CurePay where CureID = '{0}'", id);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        double total = 0;
        total = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
```

.ASPX Page

```
<%= total %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a `Label` to output your value

```
<asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" />
```

Then print out the value to the label.

```
lblValue.Text = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
//this cuts out your variable duplication problem
```

Use this instead of your `<%= total %>`

Comment: Perfect on the edit, I was just going to ask about converting to a double.

Comment: @kcray, no problem. I find using controls is an easier way to format your output, and allows you to use styling and formatting down the road.

Answer (score 3):

From your code it looks like you are using two separate variables name 'total', one local and one global. The local one is being updated, but the global one is being output on the page.

```
public partial class Payment : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       public double total; //<< keep this one

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        var id = Request.Params["ID"];
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd;
        conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("--");
        cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        var sql = String.Format(@"select sum(PayAmt) as total from CurePay where CureID = '{0}'", id);
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        double total = 0; // << remove the double keyword from this line
        total = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
```

That should sort out the problem...

Answer (score 1):

A more conventional approach would probably be to put an  on your main page, then assign it from the Page_Load function

```
<asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" />


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // database stuff
     lblNumber.Text = total;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing two different variables, a global and a local. You're setting the local var to 0 but then accessing the global, just remove the line:

```
double total = 0;
```

Comment: The code will compile because it is valid to have similarly named variables in different scopes.